# react-redux can update child smart components without updating parents?

Tags: react-redux

Imagine the following React structure:

SmartComponentA -> DumbComponentB -> SmartComponentC

Also imagine that SmartComponentA and SmartComponentC each get connected to different slices of the state in their `mapStateToProps` functions.

Lastly, imagine that we put a `console.log` in the render method of each of these components.

When I actually try this, on the first render, I see that all components log as expected. But then if I change the data for SmartComponentC, I only see a single log message (C's log message), and I don't see SmartComponentA or DumbComponentB logging anything. How is that possible? **How is react-redux getting React to update a child without updating its parents?**

I would have assumed that [the overriding](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/connect.js#L76-L78) of `shouldComponentUpdate` inside of the `connect` method would mean SmartComponentA would not get re-rendered (since its slice of the state didn't change), and therefore would cause a short-circuiting that would prevent SmartComponentC from getting re-rendered. While `connect`'s implementation is not the same as the pure render mixin, both work by changing `shouldComponentUpdate`, but the pure render docs clearly state that React will "bail out" (as they put it) if a parent doesn't need to re-render:

> for C2's subtree and C7, it didn't even have to compute the virtual DOM as we bailed out on `shouldComponentUpdate`.

[source](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html#shouldcomponentupdate-in-action)

If my question still isn't clear, here is sort of pseudo-code for the setup, and **I'm asking why I can keep typing in C's input and it only log's C's messages to the console and not A's and B's (why is it not short-circuiting)**?

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////

const SmartComponentA = (props) => {
  console.log('rendering SmartComponentA');

  return <DumbComponentB bData={props.bData} />;
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => { bData: state.bData };

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SmartComponentA);

//////////////////////////////////////////////

const DumbComponentB = (props) => {
  console.log('rendering DumbComponentB');

  return (
    <div>
      {props.bData}
      <SmartComponentC />
    </div>
  );
}

export default DumbComponentB;

//////////////////////////////////////////////

const SmartComponentC = (props) => {
  console.log('rendering SmartComponentC');

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={props.cValue} onChange={props.changeCValue} />
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => { cValue: state.cValue };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { changeCValue })(SmartComponentC);
//////////////////////////////////////////////
```

On the first render I see all log messages, then if I keep typing in the input, I only see C's log message each time I press a key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prop changes trigger the React component lifecycle which will typically trigger the lifecycle of each child component unless -- as you observe, the process can be short-circuited by shouldComponentUpdate.

But prop changes aren't they only thing that triggers the component lifecycle -- state changes do too. And that's how connect function works. The Connect component [subscribes to the store](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/connect.js#L199) and on any store change [checks to see](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/connect.js#L251) if it will update the smart component's props (based on mapStateToProps). If so it will [set it's own state](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/connect.js#L262) triggering the lifecycle functions for the Connect component and it's child.

Comment: But does that mean that React only re-renders the component whose state changes, and not the whole render tree?

Comment: Yes. It re-renders the component whose state changes. And any components downstream from that. So if you put a logger in a DumbComponentD and pass props from SmartComponentC then D will also re-render.

Comment: Okay good stuff, I guess that's what I was getting hung up on!